# Updating only the active or inview section background-position when scrolling page using stellar.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am using stellar.js adding a parallax effect to the background images of 4 sections on my page, when I initiate stellar and scroll through my page each background image position is constantly updating with the scroll which it should be and thats fine. What I was wondering however is if its possible to only initiate the background-position updating on a section when you get to that section? So if I'm on section 1 thats the only background position that updates then when I get to section 2 section 1 background-position locks or stops updating and section 2 takes over?